# How do I convert my loop output to a .txt file?

Tags: function, loops, text, output

My current code is:

```
count1 = 0
for i in range(30):
    if i%26 == 0:
        b = [i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5, i+6, i+7, i+8, i+9, i+10]
        count1 += 1

        print([count1])
        print(*b, sep=' ')

    elif (i-10)%26 == 0:
         b = [i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5, i+6, i+7, i+8, i+9]
         count1 += 1

         print([count1])
         print(*b, sep= ' ')

    elif (i-16)%32 == 0:
         b = [i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5, i+6, i+7, i+8, i+9, i+10]
         count1 += 1

         print([count1])
         print(*b, sep= ' ')
```

which produces lines:

```
[1]
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
[2]
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
[3]
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
[4]
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
```

I'd like to output these lines in a simple text file. I'm familiar with the open and write functions, but do not know how to apply them to my specific example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On GNU/Linux systems execute the program in the console,  add > and the name of the file.

Example:
Assuming that you are in the directory wich contains the executable.

./[name of the program] > [name of the file]

./helloworld > helloworld.txt

This will save all the printed text in the console in a text file.

Comment: so you're saying I'd just put this line beneath the entire code? for instance:     /users/username/Desktop > ndx.txt?